# How to parallelise 2 for loops using 1 function in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

Hi I have this code below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import pi,sin,cos
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m

image = np.zeros(shape=(201,201))

a=4
b=3
pa = 45

def dE(i,j,a,b,PA,x0,y0):
    the = -PA+90.0
    x=i - x0
    y=j - y0
    cos_a,sin_a=cos(the*pi/180.0),sin(the*pi/180.0)
    Xs = (x*cos_a - y*sin_a)**2.0 
    Ys = (x*sin_a + y*cos_a)**2.0 
    r = np.sqrt((Xs/a**2) + (Ys/b**2)) 
    return r

for i in range(0,len(image)):
    for j in range(0,len(image)):
        image[j,i] = dE(i,j,a,b,pa,100.0,100.0)

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

How do I parallelise the two for loops that are at the bottom? Thanks in advance!

I have added the full code above. Cheers Chris

Comment: Is there a reason the function `dE` is getting a lot of parameters that are unused?

Comment: And where are x and y in `dE` coming from?

Comment: Sorry I deleted some parameters when cutting the code x,y are essentially i and j but times by a constant.

Comment: And x0 and y0 modify x and y but essential if you add the step

Comment: x=i - x0 and y=j - y0

Comment: Then it should work. Sorry if that was unclear!

Comment: Please extend the code so it is complete and works. The best solution to your problem is probably to do all the computations utilizing the numpy arrays instead of using multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks for your input thats really helpful!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import pi,sin,cos
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m

image = np.zeros(shape=(201,201))

a=4
b=3
pa = 240

def dEllipse(x,y,a,b,PA):
    the = -PA+90.0
    cos_a,sin_a=cos(the*pi/180.0),sin(the*pi/180.0)
    Xs = (x*cos_a - y*sin_a)**2.0 
    Ys = (x*sin_a + y*cos_a)**2.0 
    r = np.sqrt((Xs/a**2) + (Ys/b**2)) 
    return r

x = np.arange(0-100.0, 201-100.0)
y = np.arange(0-100.0, 201-100.0)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

new_image= dEllipse(xx,yy,a,b,pa)

plt.imshow(new_image)
plt.show()
```